# Adding new column / filter to shopify data

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I would like to add calculated column to Shopify report as a filter.
The calc column is new feature (segment) created by me.
Means I would like to enhance the excising report by adding my segment to the Data pull used by Shopify to generate the report (also expose this segment to other analytics apps in shopify store)
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Didn't try anything, i looked for the  Shopify documentation but couldn't find explanation or example for that case